# Trained and Loaded Keras Sequential Model is giving different result

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have trained a model and saved in a particular directory, while training it is giving about 81% testing accuracy. I have used following commands:

```
model = Sequential()  
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128, input_length=max_len))  
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.3))  
model.add(GaussianNoise(0.2))  
model.add(LSTM(128 , dropout_W=0.3, dropout_U=0.3, return_sequences=False))  
model.add(LSTM(56, dropout_W = 0.4, dropout_U=0.4))  
model.add(Dense(1, W_regularizer=l2(0.2)))  
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))  
model.summary()  
adam = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.00)  
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam,metrics = ['accuracy'] )  
model_history = model.fit(x, y=y, batch_size=128, epochs=2, verbose=1,validation_split = 0.2)   

model_json = model.to_json()  
with open("C:/Users/twelve_user/Downloads/model3.json", "w") as json_file:  
        json_file.write(model_json)   
model.save_weights("C:/Users/twelve_user/Downloads/weights_model3.h5")  
print("Saved model to disk")  
predictions = model.predict(testx)
```

But whenever I'm trying to load the same model in different python script, the accuracy falling down i.e 76%. and sometimes I'm getting random accuracy like an untrained model. commands are given below which i have used for loading:

```
json_file = open('C:/Users/twelve_user/Downloads/model3.json', 'r')  
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()  
json_file.close()  
model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)  
model.load_weights("C:/Users/twelve_user/Downloads/weights_mode3.h5")  
print("Loaded model from disk")
```

How is this possible? Both trained and loaded model's result should be the same. As i am quite new to Keras, not able to understand where i am wrong.
Thank you for the help!  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely because you only save the model structure and the model weights. You do not save the state of your optimizer or training configuration. If you want exactly the same model use the keras function `model.save`.

Also check [this](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/) faq for more information.

**Example code**

```
predictions_before = model.predict(testx)
model.save('model3.h5')
del model

model = load_model('model3.h5')
predictions_after = model.predict(testx)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I have two script files.                    First script contains :  defining model , layers,compilation, training, prediction and then saving model (model.save and model.save_weights).                                                                   
Second script contains:  defining model.layers,compilation, model.save, del model, load_model,  prediction.                                                             Still i am getting different result from both the script files.

Comment: With model.save the model is exactly the same. Are you using the same data when you predict the second time?

Comment: yeah, same data in both files.   First file is for  training and then testing., to know the test accuracy.  For time consuming, created Second file for testing only with the  same data. So i think accuracy should be the same on both file. because data set , model defination, layers, all are same.

Comment: Did you try to use my example code in 1 script. Using the exact  same lines of code? In this case you are sure that nothing happened with the data.

Comment: yes, first script is working, same lines i have used. i think  'model.fit' is there before 'predictions_before'  variable that's why both the values (predictions_before and predictions_after) are same.    But when i am separating  last four lines of your code in other file then its giving random accuracy.

Comment: Hi, i searched and got something like 'learning phase' . Kindly have a look on link: https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html          Here it is written as "Some Keras layers (e.g. Dropout, BatchNormalization) behave differently at training time and testing time."    Is this a solution? i didnt get

Comment: That is where model fit should be (before the model.predict). You can also check if your model weights are the same by using model.get_weights() in both files. In addition, be very very sure that your data is the same. It is correct that some layers behave differently at training and testing time. But this has nothing to do with it. As the training time is when you use model.fit and the testing time is with model.predict (the latter is were your results differ)

Comment: Is there a problem of 'np.random.seed(1337)' ? I am using this at the beginning in both files.

Comment: checked.. model.get_weights() different in both files.

Comment: Model weights should only change when you apply model.fit again. Saving and reloading a model is just like writing and reading a file. Last option could be that the model layers are shuffled, but i am not sure if this is even possible if you use model.save functionality. You could add a name to each model layer to ensure this is not the case. Then you can use model.load_weights with the by_name argument.

Comment: okay.. i have removed 'model.fit' from second file. i will try to add name to each model layer and i will test again. what i am thinking.. is there a problem of environment like first file(training+testing) environment is different and second file(testing ) environment different? thats why accuracy is not same and second file is giving random accuracy. (np.random.seed())

Comment: Seeing https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4875 gives some good info. There's more to it than just save/load. You must save weights explicitly...

Answer (score 1):

For base model you can use default `model.save` as:

```
model_before.save('path')

model_after = tf.keras.models.load_model('path', custom_object=...)
```

But if your model contains the RNN\LSTM layers `model.save` can't save their states. I offer to read next issues as a start point.

[Saving and Restoring a trained LSTM in Tensor Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442098/saving-and-restoring-a-trained-lstm-in-tensor-flow)

[Save and restore RNN / LSTM models in TensorFlow](https://josehoras.github.io/saving-a-model-in-tensorflow/)